# I cannot get published blog post with wp.getRecentPosts(int)

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am using XML-RPC and Jwordpress to view my site posts.

When I Use the following code:

```
Wordpress wp = new Wordpress(Username, Password, XMLRPCURL);
List<Page> recentPost = wp.getRecentPosts(10);
```

It returns only Drafts. How can I retrieve my Published Posts with JWordpress?

Comment: do you have 10 or more drafts maybe ? Hence, it's only returning the drafts.

Comment: I don't have draft! it returns an empty list. and when I write a draft, it returns me only that draft @Shivam Verma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Thing to do is to Use Json API.
easily Install JSON on Your WordPress Site or Blog and with JSON Library for Java (Or Gson) You can get Posts and Many more stuff From Your site/Blog.
That's the Easiest way to do that I Think.